# How to handle the exceptions thrown from item reader?

Tags: exception, spring-batch, reader

I want to catch the exceptions thrown from item reader (e.g. reader not open , incorrect token exceptions etc) and handle it. Currently spring batch is throwing them as fatal exceptons and come out of the step.

Please let me know if there is any way to do it?

Comment: Read SB official doc (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#configuringSkip)

Comment: Implement Skip Policy or extend always skip class. It act as Exception Handler. All operation you can perform like writing to file on the basis of that. Method should skip validate boolean, true mean step will continue else step will stop.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue whereby I wanted to catch the
    **`org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException`** 
thrown by the **`FlatFileItemReader`** and perform some custom handling & logging. Did some research and almost reached the conclusion that I might have to write a custom reader instead of the default reader I was currently using, until I stumbled upon a gem of a section in the Spring Batch documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#interceptingStepExecution

You can write a custom implementation of the **`ItemReadListener<T>`** interface and over-ride the **`onReadError(Exception ex)`** method and then register this listener class in the corresponding step. As such, this method will then be called when the reader encounters an exception while reading from the file. The exception reference will be passed to the method as well using which you can do as you please like logging etc.
Similarly, writing a **`@OnReadError`** annotated method is also an alternative if you don't want to implement the **`ItemReadListener`** interface separately.

On a different note, if your whole purpose is to skip such exceptions that might occur while reading, you can try adding following to the chunk configuration in the XML:

```
<skippable-exception-classes>
     <include class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException"/>
</skippable-exception-classes>
```

Ref: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#configuringSkip

Problem solved! :)

Answer (score 0):

My requirement was to get control over and do custom logging and output processing when file is not present on the location or it's not accessible.

**I have written one item listener and tried it using with FlatFileItemReader or with ItemReader by setting FlatFileItemReader's strict as a false as well but I was not able to get control as listener wasn't working.**

So solution is to implement and write one custom StepExecutionListener and use it to handle any exception or event while reading, processing or writing step execution.

```
public class BatchStepExecutionListener implements StepExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {

        List<String> fileContent = new ArrayList<>();

        // Executed after the step finishes, you can handle exceptions here
        if (ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode().equals(stepExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode())) {
            Throwable exception = stepExecution.getFailureExceptions().get(0);

            fileContent.add(exception.getCause().getMessage());
            fileContent.add(exception.getMessage());


        } // When Batch Execution is success.
else if (ExitStatus.COMPLETED.getExitCode().equals(stepExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode())) {
            fileContent.add("Execution Successfully Completed");
        }

        try {
            Files.write(Paths.get("output.log"), fileContent, TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
            System.out.println("Content has been written to the file successfully.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error writing to the file: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return stepExecution.getExitStatus();
    }
}
```

**And configure this listener in batch step as follows,**

```
  @Bean
    public Step myBatchStep(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader, PersonItemProcessor processor, JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer) {

        return stepBuilderFactory.get("myBatchStep")
                .<Person, Person>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                .listener(new BatchStepExecutionListener()) **// Configure Listener Here.**
                .build();
    }
```